# cakephp How to change the X-Mailer

Tags: cakephp

Using cakePHP version 2.3.8,

I am trying to change the X-Mailer: CakePHP Email into X-Mailer: PHP mail. 
I have tried this in the controller and in the /app/Config/email.php in my 'default' settings.

```
 'X-Mailer' => 'PHP mail',
```

But not able to get it changed, really frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use addHeaders() to change it prior to sending the email.
As done here, for example:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/EmailLib.php#L638
In this case - extending the core class - one can use Configure to automatically populate the X-Mailer via configs. But you can also do it inline for each email sending functionality.

Basically, on your CakeEmail object:

```
$CakeEmail = new CakeEmail();
$CakeEmail->addHeaders(array('X-Mailer' => 'My custom X-Mailer'));
```

If set manually Cake will not add his default value 'CakePHP Email'.

Comment: thanks, I alo found out I could also do it with:                 ->setHeaders(array('X-Mailer' => 'PHP mail', in the controller. perhaps not so elegant, but I hope it is still the correct cakyway :-)

Comment: setHeaders() works, too, of course - as long as you didnt set any other headers before. Otherwise they will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, now I have only a few things left to sort, and that is my email address validation and numeric only, I have used from your website the coding as example, but the validation is a problem, same for numeric, it accepts AAA as well.

Comment: What do you mean? I cannot follow.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 2, 
Instead of setting it every time from a controller as suggested by @mark, 
you can set in the EmailConfig class, located in Config/email.php:

```
public $default = array(
  'transport' => '...',
  'from' => '...',
  'emailFormat' => 'both',
  'charset' => 'utf-8',
  'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
  'headers'=>array('X-Mailer'=>'Your App Name'),
);
```

Will send an email with these headers:

```
To: .....
X-Mailer: Your App Name
Date: ....
```